# Checking AlphaNumberic value with jQuery which is not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to work with the regex using jquery but it is not working.  I am trying to check the values that are entered in the input is AlphaNumberic if not then I want to show an alert message.

```
 if (dangerous == "Yes" && $("#dangerousUS1").val() != '' ) {

        var dangUS1 = $("dangerousUS1").val();

        var regx = /^[A-Za-z0-9 _.-]+$/;

        if (regx.test(dangUS1))
            alert("correct"); // alerts
        else
         
      
            alert('You values should include Alpha numeric values');
        }
```

The above code always shows alert message as "correct" even when I enter @ or ! .

I am using jQuery 3.4

Comment: Missing # in selector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing # in var dangUS1 = $("dangerousUS1").val(); 
Should be var dangUS1 = $("#dangerousUS1").val();